# Making Publishing Image in Page Layout Required

Tags: css, publishing-page

How can I make the publishing Image in PageLayout Required?

Answer (score 2):

Make the column Publishing Image required in the associated `ContentType` of your `PageLayout`.

**EDIT:**

To do this - Go to your `Content Type` settings:

Site Settings -> Site Content Types -> your Content Type -> your column (Publishing Image) -> Here you can set the option 'Required'.

Note that this setting applies to all `PageLayouts` associated with this `Content Type`.

Comment: This is a correct answer, but with very little detail of how to make the changes suggested. Can you please extend the answer with guidelines for how to make a field required (via GUI or code)?

Comment: @RobertLindgren - Done. :-)

Comment: I've updated the Content Type to make the field required, but SharePoint isn't forcing the user to set it... they can still check-in/publish the page without setting the value.